# c language including files without directory?

Tags: c

to include /usr/include/test/head1.h file I should write `#include "test/head1.h"` but how can I just write `#include "head1.h"` to include this file.

Comment: It depends on the compiler. For GCC you can use the `-I/usr/include/test` command line option.

Comment: Add `/usr/include/test` into the list of include directories in your compiler settings

Comment: -Linux path variable](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/path-variable) is one option.  (but not as good as just adding it to the compiler environment you are building with.)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler looks for the usual places like `/usr/include` for files.

One way to achieve this if you know your compiler already looks at `/usr/include` for include files anyway, is the following instead:

```
#include "test/head1.h"
```

This would be a good approach if you plan to include no more files from `/usr/include/test` and you know no other include directory has files with similar name to avoid conflict.

Other method would be to give compiler a hint for the directory while compiling:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/test <other-options> yourcode.c
```

Have fun writing C!

Answer (score 0):

The answer above mine is correct, but I just wanted to add some advice pertaining to making the `#include` that you want work if you're using CMake.

If you're using CMake, you can add the path up till your header in CMakeLists.txt, like so:

`target_include_directories(<projectname> PUBLIC path/to/headers)`, and you can add as many paths as you want, separated by spaces.